# error in php - foreach

Tags: php, foreach

The error I get is Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() , I have read the relevant post for foreach case, but I still dont know how to fix it. Can I know what to cause this warning and the way to fix it ?

Here is my code,

```
mysql_connect("localhost","psm","psm") or die("could not connect");
mysql_select_db("planner") or die ("could not find db!");

$output = '';
//collect
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $searchq =$_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
    $query = mysql_query("select c.*,u.username from login_user u left join calendar c on c.user_id = u.user_id where u.matrix LIKE '{$searchq}'" ) or die ("could not search");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($count == 0){ 
    $output = 'There are no search result!';
    } else {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
         $searchq = [];
         $searchq[] = $row; 
        }
}
}
    foreach($searchq as $u) {
?>
        <div class="well" align="left" width="65%" >
        <fieldset>
        <table>
            <tr><th>Matrix No:
            <?php echo $query['matrix']; ?>
            <?php foreach($query as $c){
                    if($c['user_id'] == $u['user_id']){
                        if($c['cate'] == 0){
                            echo "<p style='background: red;'>Course Name : ";
                        }else{
                            echo "<p>Title : ";
                        }
            ?>
                    <?php echo $c['title']; ?></p>
                    <p>Description ：<?php echo $c['description'];?></p>
                    <p>Location : <?php echo $c['location'];?></p>
                    <p>Start Time : <?php echo date('Y-m-d',$c['starttime']);?></p>
                    <p>End Time : <?php if($c['endtime'] != 0)echo date('Y-m-d',$c['endtime']);?></p>
            <?php }}?>
        </th></tr>
        </table>
        </div>

<?php    
    }
?>
```

Comment: For one, you don't define `$searchq` if (what I expect is a) form isn't submitted. Second, if it has been submitted but there are no rows, `$searchq` is a string instead of an array. Third, you loop around your results, but you'll only ever get one result as you reset `$searchq` to an empty array on every iteration.

Comment: i'm not really sure .... about the there are no row .. can it be more specific ?

Comment: I.e. `if ($count == 0){ ` if that returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you've got a lot of problems here.

First, don't use `mysql_` functions, as they've been deprecated since PHP 5.5, and removed in 7.0. Use `mysqli_` functions instead, or PDO.

Second, if you don't have anything in `$_POST['search']`, then `$searchq` is never initialized, and you have nothing for your foreach loop.

Second and a half, if you do pass in a `$_POST['search']`, but no results are found, you have `$searchq` as a string, so when it hits the foreach loop, it's not something foreach can use. (Honestly, your variables shouldn't do double duty like that, where you have `$searchq` as a string in the `preg_replace` and then use it as an array if there are search results.)

Third, when you use `mysqli_query()` (as you should) it requires two parameters. It's called using

```
$results = mysqli_query($connection, $statement);
```

Fourth, you're reinitializing `$searchq` in every pass through your while loop.

So, you're possibly not actually getting any results, so your while loop might never do anything, and therefore, `$searchq` is not an array that can be looped through with foreach.

What you need to do is initialize `$searchq` before your query, so you have an empty array, so that when you get down to your foreach, you at least have an empty array there.

Basically, above your foreach, you should have

```
if( !empty($searchq) && is_array($searchq))
{
    foreach(...)
}
```

or move the foreach inside your else statement after the while loop.

Comment: Fixed it. mysqli_query requires two parameters.

Comment: You fixed it for mysqli, but OP isn't using mysqli (even if they should), so still not right imo.

Comment: thanks ,i wil fixed for mysqli, and try what you say :)